# Auto code completion in VIM?

Tags: linux, vim, code-completion

Can VIM do auto code completion like what Eclipse does? Usually I connect to my Linux developing server through Putty from my Windows laptop. So, I hope I can find a plugin for VIM which can do drop-down menu like auto completion when I can type variable names in Putty, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use http://eclim.org/ - using eclipse core with VIM via plugins.

To not start the complete ecplise core but have a C/C++ member completion, try 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520

```
-   Complete namespaces, classes, structs and union members. 
-   Complete inherited members for classes and structs
(single and multiple inheritance). 
-   Complete attribute members eg: myObject->_child->_child etc...
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes, in a sense - Vim has [Completion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_24.html#24.3) commands that can help you automatically find the completion text for partial variable names.

In a nutshell, type a partial variable name and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to search for a matching name.

Comment: Is there any way to auto-complete not only the variable names but also struct/class's member and methods?

Comment: Ctrl-P
Ctrl-N
and an other one I have forgotten..
(how did you get this render for C-p?)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Vim already features that general style of code completion built-in, under the name of Omni completion.

The default installation doesn't allow for auto-invocation, but if you install [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879), that allows it to happen.

Note that, depending on the language you'll be working with, you may need additional scripts to handle auto-completion for that language, and may even need to change the auto-invoke script to recognize when to invoke the completion. Since you haven't said what programming language you'll want to work with, it's a bit hard to say if you need more than this, but I recommend checking the help file.

Comment: Yeah, it is just what I need. But, I want to the auto completion can complete the C/C++ struct/class's member and methods, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently vim has no of [plugins](http://vimawesome.com/?q=tag:autocomplete) for the auto code completion feature, I am using [youcompleteme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) plugin, combined with [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets), [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) and [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) plugins. You can tab complete the code using snippets (a small text which can be expanded for full code), and a large number of languages are supported.

For simple text files also a drop down menu comes for the words you have typed earlier.