# VI auto completion Nonesense

Tags: python, eclipse, shell, vim

I read that CTRL+P is the auto completion short cut in VI, but the recommendation given by the auto completion doesn't make that much sense to me.

Say from the re package there is a method called findall. Eclipse could recommend that method when I do CTRL+Space:

[image]

But When I tried the auto completion in VI, it could not find the findall method. the only recommendation seems like a command that I have typed before which has nothing to do with the re module.

[image]

Can Anyone give me some hints what is the auto completion story behind the CTRL+P in VI and how could I tune it up so it would be as good as Eclipse's auto completion.

(Every time I doubt the power of VI, the truth is always that it is me who lack the power to discover the beauty of VI)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto code completion in VIM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083566/auto-code-completion-in-vim)

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before ... start here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1115876.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim `<C-p>` is not the only completion shortcut available. Omni completion defined for python should be called with `<C-x><C-o>`, then use `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` to select variants. There are more completion types, all start with `<C-x>`, see [`:h ins-completion`](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/insert.txt.html#ins-completion).

It is still better to use some third-party plugin (like jedi-vim or klen/python-mode) to get python completion as they are smarter. Note that at least klen/python-mode will *not* redefine `<C-p>`. They redefine `<C-x><C-o>` by setting [`'omnifunc'` option](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/options.txt.html#.27omnifunc.27).

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional modules, vim's autocompletion only searches the current file for occurences of the string you've started typing, regardless of whether it makes sense. If you use the `tags` file, via `ctags` or other, you're able to use strings across a variety of files, rather than just the current  buffer.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934233/cscope-or-ctags-why-choose-one-over-the-other/934523#934523

Comment: @TankorSmash You are wrong: vim runtime files do hold some python completion function that does not require tags files: http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim?r=a83960ec9e6db913af1530ebe19d0126d99a7b96. But `<C-p>` is a wrong shortcut for accessing it.